# PHP error while installing composer

Tags: php, laravel, installation

[image]

I tried to install composer on windows 10, I opened the composer.exe and clicked next until I arrived to choose PHP command-line for it, so I selected php 7.0 from the dropdown menu and clicked next. then I faced with an error displaying in this screenshot.
please help me to solve this problem and tell me what should I do to install composer with PHP 7.0 command-line using.

Comment: my screenshot image could't be uploaded because i'm new user, but the text in that box is :The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.0\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.0\php.ini

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Program Output:
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php7.0.0/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Please don't add your error message as an image, but as text. Error messages as images will render the question much less searchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a file  **MSVCP140.dll** missed from my PC that is required by **php_intl.dll** extension file.
I installed it on my windows then I restart my PC and installed Composer.exe without any errors :)

click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61vwFxnnh5c) to learn how to install **.dll** files on windows.

Answer (score 0):

use composer.phar

It's more comfy as it's portable solution